# Is there a simple way to call a constructor on a vector of objects?

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I'm writing a little project in C++ using SFML, and I run into a problem. I want to draw a few lines and I would like to change the amount of them when running my program (and I want maximum of like 50 lines). So I figured, I would use a std::vector, but I need to call non default constructor on every line object and I can't find an easier way than doing it in a loop (I don't even know if I should do it anyway). I tried this:

```
std::vector<sf::VertexArray> lines(50, sf::VertexArray(2, sf::Lines));
```

but it doesn't work. (I might be wrong, it was a thing until C++ 11?).
And I ask how to do something like this (also when resizing the vector) or maybe should I find another way of storing these lines? I'm using sf::VertexArray, because I really need a line described as 2 points, and not as a rectangle.

Comment: what is the meaning of "it doesn't work" ? What errors do you get?

Comment: Did you actually try to use `std::vector<sf::VertexArray> lines(50, sf::VertexArray(2, sf::Lines));`?  It should work just fine unless `sf::VertexArray` is not copyable.

Comment: ([Which it is.](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1VertexBuffer.php#a2f2ff1e218cfc749b87f8873e23c016b))

Comment: Next time use the scientific method. So your attempt didn't work. Was it the vector's fault? Try it with a simple vector of ints. It works? Right, so the problem is your VertexArray ctor... Then you know it's not anything to do with the vector. This technique will save you from having no earthly idea what's going on. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation:

https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1VertexArray.php#a4bb1c29a0e3354a035075899d84f02f9

constructor for VertexArray is as follows:

```
sf::VertexArray::VertexArray    (   PrimitiveType   type,
std::size_t     vertexCount = 0 
)
```

so the first argument should be of PrimitiveType and the second is the count. You have it the other way around. So change:

```
std::vector<sf::VertexArray> lines(50, sf::VertexArray(2, sf::Lines));
```

to:

```
std::vector<sf::VertexArray> lines(50, sf::VertexArray(sf::Lines, 2));
```

Otherwise your code looks fine.